# Display datatables values from databse using spring injection in a ManagedBean

Tags: spring, jsf

Got this design issue with JSF + Spring :-

I got a datatable on a page to be loaded showing user details, which is to be fetched form Database.

So my jsf page has :

```
 <p:dataTable id="userTable" var="user" value="#{userBean.users}" rowKey="#{user.userID}"
                                     selection="#{userBean.selectedUser}" paginator="true" rows="10" >
```

Managed bean has:

```
private List<UserDetails> users; // getters and setters
```

Now my managed bean needs a spring injection of the helper class to fetch the users from DB.

```
@ManagedProperty(value="#{userBO}")
private UserBO userBO;
```

The problem is , spring injection happens when the object is completely instantiated. So I cannot place my `userBO.getUsersFromDataBase()` in the constructor and assign it to my `users`

I just can't figure out how to fetch users from DB,using spring injection in my managedBean. Spring needs the instantiation of the ManagedBean to be complete so that it can inject the helper class, but the jsf page requests the database values much before the ManagedBean is completely instantiated. Kinda stuck :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with spring, however in standard JSF you can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation on a method that will be invoked after construction and after dependency injection, e.g.:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    userBO.getUsersFromDataBase()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! It works but I am a bit confused now. I thought JSF view and managedBean creation kick starts at the same time..right? What if a view requests for a particular data before the managedBean is completely ready?

Comment: The bean will be created at the time it is requested for the first time. Construction, injection and @PostConstruct will be done before the first request is served.

Comment: Thanks @Matt :) Also, can I avoid my view calling my `@PostConstruct` multiple times, once my page is loaded? My page(the same above page) has a couple of `<p:dialog>`s and whenever I open a dialog it runs the @PostConstruct method. Tried changing the scope but no luck

Comment: Sometimes ViewScoped beans behave like RequestScoped ones (see [here](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)).

Comment: A lot of information in that site. Thanks! Will go through my code and check for the tags